# Are there any Event Pokemon available before the shutdown of the GTS for Generation 4 games?

Tags: pokemon-fourth-generation

Nintendo are shutting down Generation 4 and 5 GTS trade on May 20, 2014. I was wondering is there a way to put a code in the GTS to get free Pokemon. For example, Mewtwo or 3 birds.

I ask because I got a free Arceus on the GTS on my White version one time and I would love to have another Mewtwo on soul silver

Comment: Can you please re-format this/ It seems like you wrote it around a question, but formatted it as an answer.

Comment: @user30231977 - I've attempted to clean up your question based on what I thought you were asking. If this is incorrect, please rollback and edit it with what you meant :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you received the Arceus through what's called a 'Nintendo Event', which are special free Pokemon (and sometimes items) given out by Nintendo and generally coinciding with a real-world event or promotion, for example a new game, movie or the opening of a store.

Currently there are no plans by Nintendo to release new Event Pokemon for any game older than the current Generation of games (6). As Heart Gold & Soul Silver are Generation 4 games, they will not receive any events.

What you may be able to do before it shuts down, is trade with other Players using the Global Trading Link/Service and request the Pokemon you are looking for. It is highly unlikely you will get what you want, unless you offer other rare or legendary Pokemon in return.

For reference, here is the [Event-Pokemon list](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Event_Pok%C3%A9mon#Generation_IV) for Generation 4

Comment: Okay I will use my skills on the GTS  before may 20. Thanks

Comment: @user30231977 - Glad I could help :). Also welcome to Arqade! If you want, you can 'accept' the answer by clicking the checkmark that appears under the vote count. It shows the question as 'answered and accepted', and awards the answerer (and yourself) with some extra rep :)